# Como ocultar uma tabela no excel sem redimensionar o gráfico

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Eu gostaria de ocultar uma tabela porém ela alimenta um gráfico, gostaria de fazer isso sem redimensionar o gráfico. Neste gráfico é usado botões de seleção que foram formatados com macros.

Comment: Caso essa tabela seja abastecida com dados vindo de algum programa, voce pode deixar a aba que esta tabela pertence oculta e no programa apenas passar o caminho do arquivo e aba que deseja acessar. Veja mais em https://usuariosdoexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/controlando-o-acesso-as-planilhas-via-vba/  
https://www.guiadoexcel.com.br/formulario-vba-excel-de-navegacao-entre-planilhas/

Comment: O gráfico e a tabela estão na mesma aba um do lado do outro e eu não gostaria de criar outra aba só para uma tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é usar um evento na aba para redimensionar o gráfico. Optei pelo evento SelectionChange. Segue a sugestão:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
         .Height = 325 'ajustar para tamanho desejado
         .Width = 500 'ajustar para tamanho desejado
End With

End Sub
```

Se necessitar de uma introdução a eventos no VBA, segue sugestão: http://www.jorgepaulino.com/2009/09/excel-dicas-de-vba-eventos.html